List all WireGuard Connections via CLI
I have several Windows users that use WireGuard.  However, some of the configs are no longer needed.  I'm trying to clean them up but I cannot see them via the CLI.  If the user is connected  to one of them, I can see it but, if they are not currently connected, wg.exe show will not show the ones I want to clean up.  How do I show the other, unused, tunnels?
What the GUI shows:

What the CLI shows:

